# Configuration file 'C:\my\App.Config' is being used to configure all executables

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation, setup-project

I have a Visual Studio setup project that installs an application into the task scheduler and also installs a GUI application to manage some configuration parameters in the registry. This being the case, the setup project installs two different primary outputs (.exe's) as part of the process.

I am getting the following warning when I rebuild the setup project:

> Configuration file 'C:\my\App.Config'
>   is being used to configure all
>   executables

Is there any way to remove this warning? The suggested MSFT [solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228680(VS.80).aspx) apears to be to use a different setup project for each .exe, but I only want the users to have to run one installer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a `<runtime>` section in my App.Config file and once I removed this portion of the config file the issue went away.

Comment: If the runtime was the only content in your config file then you could simply delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create an installer that launches all the other installers.
This isn't a particularly helpful on microsofts part is it?

Another idea might be to take their advice and use either no config file or a custom file format so that you avoid this error.

Comment: I actually tried launching one installer from the other and it gave me an error saying another installer was already running. I'm sure this idea of having one installer launch multiple others is possible. I'm just not sure how to do it with the default installer tools in VS.

Answer (score 0):

From [Choosing a Windows Installer Deployment Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721500.aspx), it looks like the built-in windows installer maker is essentially deprecated ("Future versions of Visual Studio will not include the Visual Studio Installer project templates.")

This page also recommends *InstallShieldLE* and *Windows Installer XML Toolset*. I've just used InstallShieldLE to create an install that includes multiple executables and it appears to have worked (I'll edit this if it turns out it didn't work).

For *very* complicated installs, I've used [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) in the past with great success - I'm not sure how much extra effort NSIS requires over InstallShieldLE for simple installs.